# Getting Java to listen to the clipboard and push the new value to a list

Tags: java, list, input, copy

I'm pretty new to Java and only really know a bit of javascript just to be open about my code background.
Anyway, I want to have my program listen to the clipboard and push the newest data into a list. As new as I am to Java I'm just unsure how to do this. I am able to get my code to pull the string from the clipboard and assign it to a variable. I also got it to add the variable to the list, however, I need to have it run every time I copy something and then push it into the list as a new string. IE: I copy the word "However" then the word "What" and both of these will now be in the list.

The following is my code -

```
package clipPaste;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;

public class Clippy {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
    String result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(result);
    System.out.println(list); 

}

}
```

I had found a few very old "solutions" However they did not give me the string that was being pulled from the clip board.

I'm trying to push myself to learn more than what is taught in my current intro to Java class thus this little project of attempting to make an m8 clipboard like program in java.

*I may have solved this sort of I'll just set it up to listen for key press of control and C at the same time and direct users to do this. I know that's not userfriendly but it's a personal project I'll work on further as I learn more and it's only going to be used by like 10 people..*

Comment: You could look at The `addFlavorListener` and see if that helps.  From memory (a long time ago), I think I used a `ClipboardOwner`, basically, I had to set the contents of the clipboard and monitor for the `lostOwnership` event, which allowed me to get the new contents and then re-seed the contents, the problem with this is, you're changing the contents which might not be desirable (you might be able to seed the contents with the current contents, but you'd have to test it)

Comment: Thats a very interesting question you got there! +1

Answer (score 0):

Every time this code runs, it runs independently of when it ran before. So every time you run this code, it creates a new empty list `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`. If you want the list to persist throughout multiple runs of this program, you need to store the list somewhere and load it the next time the program runs, like a file. The other alternative is to encapsulate this program with a `while()` loop so that it runs forever in the background, waiting for new clipboard input, but I don't know if that is something you want to happen.

Comment: I'd want the program to pause as it waits for a new string to be added to the clipboard rather than have it run forever (similar to waiting for input in a simple form that would have output after input is given). As for saving the list I'm ridiculously new to Java so I'm not sure how to save it to have it load the next run (only two classes into my first Java class) So this might not be the best first project but I learn best diving into something I feel I can get actual results from and applies to making my current job slightly easier rather than just making simple math solving programs.

Comment: I'm unsure if there is something like a "Clipboard content has changed"-event in Windows where you can subscribe to. And if there is one, it's probably too complicated for a small programm.
You can always do a simple approach as described before. `while(true) { ... }`, get current clipboard contents, check whether they have changed and then sleep for example for `500ms` before doing the next check. The program then just runs in the background, most times it just sleeps.

Comment: @Zabuza unfortunately, I don't think the infinite loop approach will work for me as I need to make a GUI that allows the user to click on one of the displaying list items to copy back onto the clipboard. From my, honestly basic understanding of this, the loop would stop the rest of the code needed from running as it would never read the rest of it. Correct? Sorry if I'm overlooking something or am unaware of how looping works in Java vs other languages.

Comment: That is correct. However you could start the clipboard-watcher in a new thread. Then it works independently and does not stop the rest of the app. That's fairly easy if you know how to. Therefore you need to extend from Javas class `Thread` and add some code to the `run()` method, that's all. By that you can add a event-mechanism to the thread where others may subscribe to. But that might be to hard for a beginner, good luck!